# Which scriptures define the science of Mudras? And what are they used for?

Tags: scripture, yoga, book-recommendation

It would be great to also have some reference to translations (if any) in english or hindi of the scriptures which deal with the science of mudras.

Also would like to know what different purpose the mudras serve.

Thank You

Comment: @SwiftPushkar second part of my question seems to be answered but not the primary question and it does not have any exact reference to any scripture. Thanks for pointing me to that.

Comment: Yes ,  that's why not voted to close.IMO you have to change the main focus of your question accordingly.

Comment: Mudras are mentioned in Hatha Yoga Pradipika,Gheranda Samhita and also i think in Siva Samhita..Mudras are subtle forms of asana postures ..Apart from Yoga several hasta-mudras are used in Puja rituals..Tantra texts say the no. of such mudras is 108 but 55 are commonly used..On [this](http://www.astrojyoti.com/mudras.htm) page you can see almost all mudras used in Pujas..Also if i'm not mistaken mudras are mentioned in Devi Bhagvatam as well..that are used in Gayatri upasana..